# Delphi 2010 - Detect file growth in a mapped drive

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I'm trying to detect when a file is being written into a mapped drive. I need to wait for the file to be completely uploaded to the mapped drive before I start to process it. The problem is that the application that writes the file to the mapped location does not lock the file.

I've tried the following:

-check if file is in use => not working because file is not locked exclusively.I can rename it while it is being written to the mapped drive.

-get the last access filestamp comparison => not working. I should get an error because the file attributes change but i dont.

-get the file size => not working. it already shows me the final size of the file.

Is there any way I can detect the growth of the file so i can wait until it is over? All the tests listed above work ok on local files but not on that mapped drive where the files are written by a 3rd party tool. If is use explorer and press F5 I can see that the file size is growing.

Comment: You need to fix the root problem.

Comment: @David - meaning that is the only way, or that it needs fixing anyway?

Comment: Should we take it you have no control over the writer-app?

Comment: I can't really see how anyone can help here with no details provided. Any hacky workaround would surely rely on knowledge of the systems and code involved. Perhaps the writer broadcasts a message when it is done. We can only guess. Can't you be specific?

Comment: I have no control over the sender application. I was thinking on simulating the view properties from Explorer and then store the size into a variable and wait 50ms and then retrieve again the size.If they differ then it is still being copied. The application that puts the file on the shared folder it's part from an automation process i do not control. I have no settings to define there. I don't no why all the methods above fail but the explorer shows on refresh that a file is being written, it grows.

Comment: *"-get the last access filestamp comparison => not working. I should get an error because the file attributes change but i don't"* What exactly is not working specifically? Why would you expect an error querying the timestamp? If you have the file open for reading, you can use `GetFileTime()` without error. Otherwise, you can use `FindFirstFile()` or `GetFileAttributesEx()`, neither of which require you to open the file since they get metadata from the filesystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all the suggestions received I managed to come up with a solution. Searching over the internet I managed to get a function that gets the size of the file in bytes like it is displayed in The Explorer. The problem was that in order to work i had to wait for 5 seconds before taking the second value from the file properties. This works but in order to be usable in an automation system I have to make it run in a separate thread because I need to use this in a loop(`for i:=listbox1.items.count-1 downto 0 do begin`) to check all the files from a listbox in order to know which can be procesed.

```
function GetFileSize_mmg(const FileName: string): Int64;
var
  fad: TWin32FileAttributeData;
begin
  if not GetFileAttributesEx(PChar(FileName), GetFileExInfoStandard, @fad) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  Int64Rec(Result).Lo := fad.nFileSizeLow;
  Int64Rec(Result).Hi := fad.nFileSizeHigh;
end;


function does_size_changes(filename:string; delay:integer;memo_loguri:Tmemo): boolean;
var size1,size2:int64;
begin
result:=false;
size1:=GetFileSize_mmg(filename);
sleep(delay);
size2:= GetFileSize_mmg(filename);

if size1 <> size2 then
begin
result:=true;
memo_loguri.Lines.Add(datetimetostr(now)+' - file "'+filename+'" is growing: ' +inttostr(size1)+' < '+inttostr(size2));
end

else
begin
result:=false;
memo_loguri.Lines.Add(datetimetostr(now)+' - file "'+filename+'" can be used: '+ inttostr(size1)+' = '+inttostr(size2));
end;
end;
```

Thanks